# Handling Django Model Fields that may be "None" to avoid AttributeError

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model that looks something like this :

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    current_job = models.ForeignKey(
        Job,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
    )
```

I get an instance of "Candidate", and try to save some of the values into a dictionary

```
candidate = Candidate.objects.get(first_name = "John")

data['first_name'] = candidate.first_name
data['last_name'] = candidate.last_name
data['company_name'] = candidate.current_job.company
```

This works fine when all values and foreign-keys are properly populated.

However, when any of the values of the fields are None, especially important regarding the ForeignKey relationships, I'll hit an AttributeError, something like : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'company'

I want to properly handle the "None" case for any Field in the Model.
I've found these two work-arounds for it right now, but neither seem satisfactory to me.

A) I can put a try-except around EACH and EVERY field (which doesn't seem correct as my models get to ~20 fields)

```
try:
    data['first_name'] = candidate.first_name
    data['last_name'] = candidate.last_name
except:
    pass
try:
    data['company_name'] = candidate.current_job.company
```

B) I can convert the instance to a dict like this and use a .get() since that never raises an Exception.

```
candidate_dict = candidate.__dict__
data['first_name'] = candidate_dict.get('first_name')
```

Is there a better way of handling the possibility of field values being None without handling an AttributeError exception on each and every single field?

Answer (score 1):

First You need to check following query will return a record or not. You can put in try catch and handle the `DoesNotExist` exception.

```
candidate = Candidate.objects.get(first_name="John")
```

if candidate record present then you do not need to handle exception for 
first_name, middle_name, last_name fields.

Since current_job is FK field and it can be null so before getting Job model fields data you first need to check the candidate related current_job field is not null